# when audioqueue play lpcm decoded from ffmpeg, the elapsed time of audio queue exceeds the duraion of the media

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, pcm, audioqueueservices

When play the lpcm data decoded from ffmpeg with audioqueue, the elapsed time got by `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime` exceeds the duration of media. But when decode the same media with AVFoundation framework, the elapsed time equals duration of the media, and so when read media by ffmpeg with no decoded, then send the compressed media data to audioqueue, the elapsed time also equals duration of the media. The **AudioStreamBasicDescription** set as following:

```
    asbd.mSampleRate = 44100;
    asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
    asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    asbd.mReserved = 0;
```

When playing with data decoded from AVFoundation, the setting of **AudioStreamBasicDescription** is the same as above. By my test found that `AudioTimeStamp.mSampleTime` got by `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime` is different between ffmpeg and AVFoundation, the value of ffmpeg is greater than AVFoundation. So I want to know how this happen, and how to fix it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here the mistake is `asbd.mSampleRate = 44100` is not always right, so sometimes the result is right, but others is wrong. Then you should set the `asbd.mSampleRate = audioCodecCtx->sample_rate`, this always work well!